# Zerar Page a cada click

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Tenho na figura acima este UserForm pequeno com três pages.
Na primeira page, ao clicar no botão Habilitar, é inserido a próxima data com o TextBox Data como False, para o usuário não alterar.
O botão Habilitar habilita também o TextBox Previsto e os botões Inserir e Limpar.
Ao clicar na segunda page, tenho outra configuração, claro, e posso inserir dados atualizados.
Ao clicar novamente na primeira page, caso o usuário não tenha tomada nenhuma ação ao clicar no botão Habilitar, gostaria que a page volte ao seu estado original.
Estou utilizando este código, e gostaria de saber sé é realmente desta forma.
Vou utilizar para as três pages.

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Click(ByVal Index As Long)
    With Me.MultiPage1
        If .Value = 0 Then Call Me.RestauraControles0
        If .Value = 1 Then Call Me.RestauraControles1
    End With
End Sub
```

Me.RestauraControles0 limpa tudo e deixa habilitado somente o botão Habilitar.

Comment: `RestauraControles0` isto é uma função dentro do formulário ou de um módulo?

Comment: RestauraControles0 está dentro do formulário.
Simplesmente deixa habilitado somente o botão Habilitar.

Comment: RestauraControles0 está dentro do formulário. Simplesmente deixa habilitado somente o botão Habilitar. Limpa todos os controles textbox da primeira page. E é isso que eu estou querendo: selecionou a primeira page, limpa tudo com o RestauraCOntroles0.

Comment: RestauraControles1 faz o mesmo ao clicar na segunda page. Ou deveria.

Comment: `Sub RestauraControles0()
    Me.tbData0.Enabled = True
    Me.tbData0.Text = ""
    Me.tbData0.Enabled = False
    Me.tbPrevisto0.Enabled = True
    Me.tbPrevisto0.Text = ""
    Me.tbPrevisto0.Enabled = False
    Me.btInserir0.Enabled = False
    Me.btLimpar0.Enabled = False
    Me.btHabilitar0.SetFocus
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

O código funciona da maneira que você está realizando, mas se quiser algo mais genérico crie um Módulo de Classe ou faça da seguinte maneira:

Como não sei como está toda estrutura do seu formulário e o que realmente deseja da página 2, este é um exemplo para aprender a realizar loops nos controles do formulário e generalizar algumas tarefas que podem funcionar em todas as páginas.

## Código

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()
    Dim controle As Control
    Dim pagina_atual As Long
    Dim tudo_vazio As Boolean
    tudo_vazio = True
    With Me.MultiPage1
        pagina_atual = .Value
        For Each controle In .Pages(pagina_atual).Controls
            If TypeName(controle) = "TextBox" Then
                If Trim(controle.Value) <> "" Then
                    'Debug.Print controle.Name
                    tudo_vazio = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next controle
        If tudo_vazio Then
            For Each controle In .Pages(pagina_atual).Controls
                If TypeName(controle) = "CommandButton" Then
                    'Debug.Print controle.Name
                    If Not Trim(controle.Name) Like "*habilitar*" Then
                        controle.Enabled = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next controle
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

## Explicação

Em que realiza o loop nos controles de formulário da página atual e verifica se não há Caixas de Textos vazias.

#### Página Atual

O código `pagina_atual = Me.MultiPage1.Value` retorna o valor da página da multipágina selecionada.

#### Loop nos controles

```
For Each controle In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(pagina_atual).Controls
Next controle
```

Realiza o loop em todos os controles da página da multipágina selecionada.

#### Verificar se é caixa de texto

```
If TypeName(controle) = "TextBox" Then
End If
```

Verifica se o controle é uma caixa de texto.

#### Verificar se algo foi escrito na Caixa de Texto

```
If Trim(controle.Value) <> "" Then
End If
```

Verifica se o valor da caixa de texto é diferente de vazio.

#### Caso não seja vazio

```
tudo_vazio = False
Exit For
```

Caso o controle não esteja vazio, ou seja, com algum valor. Altera a flag `tudo_vazio` para False e sai do loop.

#### Verifica a flag `tudo_vazio`

```
If tudo_vazio Then
End If
```

Caso `tudo_vazio` seja verdadeiro, continua com o código.

#### Loop controles e verificação botão

Da mesma forma que anteriormente, o loop nos controles é relizado e é verificado se é Botão de Comando.

#### Verifica Nome do Botão de Comando

Como os Text_Box estão todos vazios, quer dizer que não houve alteração. Então todos os botões que não contenham a palavra habilitar no nome serão desabilitadas com `controle.Enabled = False`

```
If Not Trim(controle.Name) Like "*habilitar*" Then
End If
```

Comment: Valeu e muito obrigado!

Comment: @PauloSemblano Você pode também utilizar como função genérica para "zerar" cada página desejada... Ao inves de utilizar o evento `MultiPage1_Change`

Comment: Em função me embaralho um pouco. Rsrsrsrsrsrs